# How to get information in javascript to appear in html

Tags: javascript, html

The below code is supposed to make a shopping cart.However, I am unsure of how I do the conversion from javascript to html (I don't quite know how to describe it, sorry)

I am trying to have javascript build a table that has the values of the items within it, along with buttons to build the shopping cart.  I initially was browsing the web to find how to do it, and thought that using `document.getElementById().innerhtml` would work, and referencing it in the body, however it seems that it is not functioning as intended.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> 
            ACME Corp Shopping Cart
    </title>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "shopstyle.css">
    <script type = "text/javascript", language = "javascript">
            alert("YAS");
            var products = [];
            var cart = [];

            //label individual products below in individual lists, and then have the product put through the product_setup function

            var product1 = ["Anvil", "Premium Grade Iron", 119.99];
            var product2 = ["Female Roadrunner Costume", "Guaranteed to attract Male Roadrunners", 54.99];

            function product_setup(product){
                        var productID = product[0];
                        var product_desc = product[1];
                        var qty = 1;
                        var price = product[2];

                        var newProduct = {
                            product_id: null,
                            product_desc: null,
                            product_qty: 0,
                            product_price: 0.00,
                        };
                        newProduct.product_id = productID;
                        newProduct.product_desc = product_desc;
                        newProduct.product_qty = qty;
                        newProduct.product_price = price;


                        products.push(newProduct);
            }


            product_setup(product1);
            product_setup(product2);    



            function product_table() {
                var html = "<table border = '1|1' >";

                html += "<td>Product Name</td>";
                html += "<td>Product Description</td>";
                html += "<td>Price</td>";
                html += "<td>Add to Cart</td>";


                for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i ++) {

                    html += "<tr>";
                    html += "<td>" + products[i].product_name + "</td>";
                    html += "<td>" + products[i].product_desc + "</td>";
                    html += "<td>" + products[i].product_price + "</td>";
                    html += "<td>" + <button type = 'submit' onclick = 'addCart(products[i].product_name, this)'>Add to Cart</button> + "</td>";
                    html += "</tr>";

                }

                html += "</table>";

                document.getElementById("location1").innerHTML = html;

            }
            product_table();

            function addCart(product_id) {

                        for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
                            if (products[i].product_id == product_id) {
                                var cartItem = null;
                                for (var k = 0; k < cart.length; k++) {
                                    if (cart[k].product.product_id == products[i].product_id) {
                                        cartItem = cart[k];
                                        cart[k].product_qty++;
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                                if (cartItem == null) {

                                    cartItem = {
                                        product: products[i],
                                        product_qty: products[i].product_qty 
                                    };
                                    cart.push(cartItem);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        renderCartTable();

                    }



                  function subtractQuantity(product_id)
                    {

                        for (var i = 0; i < cart.length; i++) {
                            if (cart[i].product.product_id == product_id) {
                                cart[i].product_qty--;
                            }

                            if (cart[i].product_qty == 0) {
                                cart.splice(i,1);
                            }

                        }
                        renderCartTable();
                    }



                    function addQuantity(product_id)
                    {

                        for (var i = 0; i < cart.length; i++) {
                            if (cart[i].product.product_id == product_id) {
                                cart[i].product_qty++;
                            }  
                        }
                        renderCartTable();
                    }

                    function removeItem(product_id)
                    {

                        for (var i = 0; i < cart.length; i++) {
                            if (cart[i].product.product_id == product_id) {
                                cart.splice(i,1);
                            }

                        }
                        renderCartTable();
                    }


                    function renderCartTable() {
                        var html = '';
                        var ele = document.getElementById("location2");
                        ele.innerHTML = ''; 

                        html += "<table id='tblCart' border='1|1'>";
                        html += "<tr><td>Product ID</td>";
                        html += "<td>Product Description</td>";
                        html += "<td>Quantity</td>";
                        html += "<td>Price</td>";
                        html += "<td>Total</td>";
                        html += "<td>Action</td></tr>";
                        var GrandTotal = 0;
                        for (var i = 0; i < cart.length; i++) {
                            html += "<tr>";
                            html += "<td>" + cart[i].product.product_id + "</td>";
                            html += "<td>" + cart[i].product.product_desc + "</td>";
                            html += "<td>" + cart[i].product_qty + "</td>";
                            html += "<td>" + cart[i].product.product_price + "</td>";
                            html += "<td>" + parseFloat(cart[i].product.product_price) * parseInt(cart[i].product_qty, 10) + "</td>";
                            html += "<td><button type='submit' onClick='subtractQuantity(\"" + cart[i].product.product_id + "\", this);'/>Subtract Item</button> &nbsp <button type='submit' onClick='addQuantity(\"" + cart[i].product.product_id + "\", this);'/>Add Item</button> &nbsp<button type='submit' onClick='removeItem(\"" + cart[i].product.product_id + "\", this);'/>Remove Item</button></td>";
                            html += "</tr>";

                           GrandTotal += parseFloat(cart[i].product.product_price) * parseInt(cart[i].product_qty, 10);            

                    }

                    document.getElementById("location3").innerHTML = GrandTotal;
                    html += "</table>";
                    ele.innerHTML = html;
                }

            renderCartTable();

        </script>

</head>
<body>

<br>
<p id="location1"> </p>
<br/>

<h2> Shopping Cart </h2>
<p id="location2"> </p>

<h2>Grand Total:</h2>
<p id="location3"> </p>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your script is running before the `document.body` DOM is ready for manipulation. Other frameworks solve this by executing code in an `onReady` handler. For this simple example, just move your `<script>` tag into the `<body>` itself at the end. See if your issue changes.

Comment: Your script is in the head, so the body does not exist yet when the script runs. Just place your script as the last tag in the body or put it in a seperate file.

Comment: Hi, first, if you aren't sure of how to explain what you've tried technically, you can tell us your functional needs. Then, thanks for providing your code, but as it's a bit long, you can provide a jsfiddle (jsfiddle.net) in order to allow us to run your code. Have a good day

Comment: Also, you are missing quotes on this line: `html += "<td>" + <button type`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is always considered the best when you include your `<script>` tags after `<body>`. DOM elements that you try to access in your script are usually available only after the entire page has loaded. Your script should start running only **after web page's body is created** since you're expecting contents to be added to `<body>`